# Looping a VBA statement to check for empty cells before continuing sub

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new to VBA. How would I change the below code to check cells Q1:Q5 rather than just Q1. Also, is it possible to temporarily highlight the cell that's empty?

```
If ActiveSheet.Range("Q1").Value = "" Then
    Answer = MsgBox("You have not entered all of the required details.", vbCritical, "Error")
Exit Sub
End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For highlighting cells that are empty use Conditional Formatting (can be applied without code)

See Debra Dalgleish's [site](http://www.contextures.com/xlCondFormat01.html)

**Code Question**

```
Sub CellCheck()
Dim rng1 As Range
Set rng1 = Range("Q1:Q5")
If Application.CountA(rng1) <> rng1.Cells.Count Then _
    Answer = MsgBox("You have not entered all of the required details.", vbCritical, "Error")
End Sub
```